# How to determine the constant of integration when solving a DE given by Ampere's law?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields, differential-equations

A cylindrical conductor with axis along the z-axis carries a current density $J\mathbf k$. From my understanding,
$$
\mathbf B=\frac12 \mu_0 Jr\hat{\boldsymbol {\phi}}.
$$
However, if we consider an alternative solution
$$
\mathbf B=\left(\frac12 \mu_0 Jr+C_1\right)\hat{\boldsymbol {\phi}}+C_2\mathbf  k,
$$
where $C_1,C_2$ are arbitrary constants, then it is easy to check that this new $B$ also satisfy Ampere's law, because constants simply disappear after differentiation.

Presumably, $C_1=C_2=0$, **but how can I prove it mathematically?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could without some other external information. You should be able to add any curl-free and divergence-free, time-independent magnetic field to your solution.

Imagine actually doing this experiment. The current through your conductor produces the magnetic field of your first expression, but when you measure the magnetic field, you find there is an offset of about $10^{-4}$ T caused by the Earth's background magnetic field.

Of course if you were to numerically take the curl of the field you had measured, it would be zero outside the conductor and $\mu_0 J\hat{k}$ inside the conductor.

Comment: I have some study material for electromagnetism - and all of them assume the constants to be zero without any justification. I am very unhappy about this. Why nobody cares about it?

Comment: O if I start with integrating the Biot-Aavart law, then there would be no constants...

Comment: @MaJoad If you integrate, there are constants. Nobody cares because Maxwell's equations have solutions that can be superposed.

Answer (score 1):

Set $J=0$, then there should be no magnetic field (no current, no field), i.e., $\textbf{B}=0$, hence $C_1=0$ and $C_2=0$.

Comment: This is essentially providing the 'other external information' that Rob Jeffries' answer says is necessary. Another way of stating the same information that would force $C_1=C_2=0$ would be to state the boundary condition that $B$ vanishes at infinity.

Comment: @jacob1729 B cannot vanish at infinity if you go in $z$ direction - the whole thing is cnfusing.

Comment: If $J$ is confined to a finite region of space then you can easily show that $B$ goes to $0$ at infinity, see the Biot-Savart integral. In your problem the current extends along an infinite long line and that is why B is not zero uniformly towards $\infty$.